# Laravel Eloquent get sale count for every day of a month

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Trying to get the sale count for every day of the month in a list, but currently getting an error on the groupBy clause.

Correct output:
For example there are 31 days in december, and this output shows how many sales there are in each day. If there are no sales, it says 0.

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Sales table:

1. id
2. total
3. created_at
4. updated_at

```
$year = 2020;
$month = 12;
$daysCount = Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, 1)->daysInMonth;

$salesData = Sale::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, 1), Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $daysCount)])
->groupBy('created_at')
->get();

dd($salesData);
```

Comment: Edit: Removed count() from the builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the groupby clause should include all the columns you select, since you did not use 'select' statement then all columns is selected, witch conflict with this rule.

you should use select, or selectRaw to strictly identify your selected columns,
and you can use [DAYOFMONTH](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofmonth-function.php) function to get the day of the month:

```
 $salesData = Sale::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, 1), Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $daysCount)])
->selectRaw('DAYOFMONTH(created_at) monthDay,count(*)')
->groupBy('monthDay')
->get();
```

Comment: This fixed the error, but the output is not correct it doesn't group by the days of the month

Comment: This worked, but it doesn't return the days without any sales. Any idea how I can get those as well?

Comment: try use 'having' after groupby:->selectRaw('DAYOFMONTH(created_at) monthDay,count(*) theCount')->->groupBy('monthDay')->having('theCount','!=',null)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an unaggregated column, try with:

```
    $salesData = Sale::selectRaw("COUNT(*) as count, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y %m %e') as created_data")
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, 1), Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $daysCount)])
        ->groupBy('created_at')
        ->get();
```

Comment: This gave me all the records in the month, without grouping by day or counting them

Comment: I got this:

Could not parse '2020 12 27': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2020 12 27) at position 5 (1): Unexpected character

Comment: renamed alias, anyway